# How to repair a broken spindle in a French Country dining chair

Tags: furniture

How can I repair a spindle on a French Country chair, only the top half of the spindle is broken. I don't want to take the chair apart if I can avoid it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExhange. I don't think this is possible without partial disassembly, and also you would often replace a broken spindle rather than repair it. If the diameter of the spindle is equivalent to a commercial dowel a non-woodworker can expect to be able to do this but if it's a weird in-between size you probably can't expect to make a repair like this. Also note that in either case refinishing to match will be a big secondary challenge. Based on this, how do you think you want to proceed?

Comment: You're quite lucky that it's the center one.

Comment: @gnicko, you mean because it doesn't need to be bent? In terms of possibly being able to get it into position without disassembly, if one had to pick the outer two would probably be the best ones to be broken because there's so much extra potential flex, and room to manoeuvre. The middle three, although they have to be bent least (not at all?) present the most awkward positioning and only really flex in one axis.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the right way to fix this is to take much of the back apart and replace the broken bit.

I have a slightly hack-y suggestion, though.

Flush cut the spindle at the bottom. (Or rough cut and trim flush with a chisel.)

Loosen the glue holding the spindle at the lower crosspiece. This might be a combination of strategic dampening and/or hairdryer heat.

Twist the spindle out and remove it if possible. (This will make the next step less cumbersome.)

Drill out the remains of the old spindle from the top hoop. Be as accurate as possible, both in terms of size and centering.

Cut the top of the spindle square and chamfer the edge slightly for easier insertion.

Possibly ream out the lower crosspiece a tiny bit to make re-insertion a little easier.

Dry fit and mark where the spindle emerges from the bottom of the lower crosspiece. Cut the spindle.

Reassemble with a bit of glue and dab some paint where the spindle met the seat.

Comment: Do I understand this right, you are omitting the spindle from the crosspiece to the seat?

Comment: Yes, there will be a gap. Although it just occurred to me that you might — with a little luck — be able to drill a hole all the way through the seat and feed a new spindle down, through the seat, then up. (You’d need the right size dowel.)

Comment: This is certainly *a* solution, and in line with my principle that any potentially useful Answer is upvoted (contrary to widespread practice!) +1 from me. Although I think for this to work right the remaining portion of the spindle needs to be noticeably longer than the visible gap if you get what I mean.

Comment: Another, simpler, methodology to get to the same end point might be possible. If the spindles can be released from the crosspiece it could be cut off at the bottom, slid through the crosspiece up into the back rest, glued home and after the glue has set flush cut to the underside of the crosspiece. I doubt however that this is going to be doable, as the chair doesn't seem likely to me to be glued together with a protein glue, and releasing a PVA bond may prove functionally impossible (certainly without compromising the adjacent bonds *and* the paint).

Answer (score 2):

I like @Aloysius-Defenestrate 's answer, but suggest that it be taken one more step.

- Start by loosening the dowel by twisting it, if possible, and removing it in its entirety.  If it cannot be twisted loose then cut it flush top and bottom at the middle crosspiece and the lower one.
- Drill out the remaining dowel pieces from the middle and lower crosspieces. The lower one should be drilled deep enough to accommodate moving the new dowel further down than its final position.
- Cut a replacement dowel long enough to extend both into the bottom and top crosspieces adequately to be glued into place.
- Slide it down through the center crosspiece down into the over deep bottom hole and then back up into the top crosspiece hole.
- You will have to decide when to place the glue to the dowel depending upon how difficult placing the dowel.  IF it can be fit and at least partially removed before gluing then due so, otherwise, take the risk and glue it during the initial fitting.

Alternatively, as I wrote this, it occurred to me that the dowel does not have to take much stress for the chairback, and it might be possible to keep the bottom portion of the dowel as is and perform this operation for the top section only.  You would still have to drill the centerpiece dowel out long enough to accommodate inserting the new dowel as above.  Since the strength of the chairback is only affected a little, the chair should still support normal use well.